Supported list of keys on NSTextLayoutManager method setRenderingAttributes
I'm trying to use setAttributes onNSTextLayoutManager. The documentation doesn't mention any supported keys (so, I figured they'd all work). However, while .foregroundColor does work, changing font size via .font does not.
Is there a list of supported NSAttributedString.Key documented anywhere? Thanks
